# docker run in detached mode - basic question

Tags: docker

I run it in detached mode with,

```
docker run -d busybox:1.24
```

But it does not show up in `docker ps`

what is the reason? Should not it be working?

Should i have to pass "running command" like `sleep 1000`?

EDIT: Seems like the container stops when there is nothing to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what the CMD directives says in your Dockerfile. If you dont run a script or program that is running continuous the the container will simple end right away.

To see the status of the container: -a shows even exited containers

```
docker ps -a
```

To see what happend when it ran

```
docker logs <container-id>
```

To run a cmd prompt

```
docker run -it <container-id> /bin/bash
```

To run in detached mode you need a script or command that will wait eg:

```
sleep infinite
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run `docker ps`, you will only see a list of containers that are **running**.

To see **all** containers, including ones that are stopped, created, exited, restarting etc, you should use `docker ps -a`.

The `busybox` container isn’t running anything. So it will just exit as soon as it starts.

If you do `docker run -d busybox:1.24 sleep 10`, then run `docker ps`, you will see the running container - until the `sleep` process exits (after 10 seconds). At which point, you’ll need to use `docker ps -a` again.